# Multiple crosstabs in the summary band using iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, crosstab

I have implemented a *JasperReports* report (using *iReport*) which consist of multiple crosstabs in the summary band which works successfully with the following stricture

```
Summary {
    Crosstab 1
    Page Break
    Crosstab 2
    Page Break
    Crosstab 3
    Page Break
    Crosstab 4
    Page Break
    Crosstab 5
 }
```

The user requirement is to remove the page break and show crosstabs one by one without breaks like this structure :

```
 Summary {
        Crosstab 1
        Crosstab 2
        Crosstab 3
        Crosstab 4
        Crosstab 5
     }
```

But when I removed the page break, **the crosstabs get overlapped**.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting property `Position Type` to `Float` or `Fix relative to bottom`, I think float should solve your problem. If that doesn't work you'll probably have to make crosstab elements large enough to fit the actual data.